# how to change different background colors using only one button

Tags: html

I want to change background color that is I need to change my background color first to red using button,then to green and then to blue by using the same button.

Comment: Hi Thejus, you should try firts, and show your code and errors or why dont you get what you wanted.

Comment: Do you know javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This is a example, of what you want.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
    var colorIndex = 0;
    function changeColor() {
        var col = document.getElementById("body");
        if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
        colorIndex++;
    }
</script>
    <body id='body'>
    <button onclick="changeColor();">Change color</button>
    </body>
</html
```

What I do here was:
1.Give `<body>` an `id`
2.Make button that call function on click.
3.Call the body by using it id (`document.getElementById('body')`) and make it change the background color (`document.getElementById('body').style.background = colors[colorIndex]`)
Hope this help.