# How to change background colors (green/red) in empty HTML on certain keypress?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, events

Does someone has solution on how to change background color in HTML on certain button press, example letter A.
Whenever I press button A color switches to other color (red to green, or green to red), and stays that way. But bonus would be that it works when I'm not focused on web browser, so it can work when I use other app over browser. Sorry for noob question and language barrier. Thank you for replies.

Similar to this link, but should be on presskey button:
[how to change different background colors using only one button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340532/how-to-change-different-background-colors-using-only-one-button)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Comment: The browser needs to be focused in order for JavaScript to receive Events, so forget about your other idea. Also, please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve] of your best code after an extensive research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to make it so that when the A key is pressed from another window, it'll activate, since on most operating systems, the keyboard is automatically focused to the window that's focused. There could possibly be an application for it, but it would be really inconvenient to use (if you're trying to press the A key inside of that app, it'll go to your window instead).

But, if you do find a way, here's your answer.
For reference, I would assume that the background of your website is already red.

```
      let isRed = true;
  document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'a') {
      if (isRed) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        isRed = false;
      } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        isRed = true;
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I'm gonna use letter ć, that I don't use at all. So, it won't collide with other functions. Could you please write down whole implementation of code, without blue color.

Comment: Ah, smart. I didn't even think of that. Well, good luck!

Comment: Follow-up: I saw you edited your message -- I just wanted to clarify my code didn't contain the color blue in the first place, so I'm kinda confused lol

Comment: Yes, it seems that is not possible. It seems possible with Python and PyWin library, but it makes it less secured and even dangerous. But, would it work with MiDi, or USB device with buttons? Would it use lil bit different pipeline, and what would happen with Listeners events and how would it impact on performance or else?

Answer (score 2):

you can use JavaScript to detect the keypress event and changing the background color

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Change background color on keypress</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Press the 'A' key to change the background color!</p>
    <script>
      var colors = ["red", "green"];
      var currentColorIndex = 0;
      document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
        if (event.key === "a" || event.key === "A") {
          var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
          body.style.backgroundColor = colors[currentColorIndex];
          currentColorIndex = (currentColorIndex + 1) % colors.length;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since styles should be in CSS rather than in JavaScript, all you need is to [Element.classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) a class (like ".is-active") on the `<html>` Element (the `document.documentElement`):

```js
addEventListener("keydown", (evt) => {
  if (evt.key === "a") document.documentElement.classList.toggle("is-active");
});
```

```css
.is-active body { background-color: gold; }
/* or like:   .is-active #someID { background-color: gold; } */
```

For the `"ć"` key, well, simply use that character instead of `"a"`